# Pandas merge not working as expected in streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

#### Summary

When using pandas *merge* function within a callback function, the dataframe is not updated correctly. However, the pandas *drop* function works as expected

Note that although i have turned on st.cache. The same behavior is noted when removing the cache function as well.

#### Steps to reproduce

**Code snippet:**

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd


@st.cache(allow_output_mutation=True)
def read_df():
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'col1':[1,2],
        'col2':['A','B']
    })
    return df

df = read_df()

def do_something():
    global df
    df_new = pd.DataFrame({
        'col1':[1,2],
        'col3':["X","Y"]
    })
    df.drop(['col2'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    df = df.merge(df_new, on="col1")

st.button("Do Something", on_click=do_something, args =())

download_csv = df.to_csv().encode('utf-8')
st.download_button('Download', data = download_csv, file_name = 'download_csv.csv', mime='text/csv')
```

Steps to reproduce behavior

- click on "Do Something" button
- click on "Download" button

**Expected behavior:**

I would expect the downloaded csv to be displayed

```
   col1 col3
0     1    X
1     2    Y
```

**Actual behavior:**

However, i get the following output instead

```
   col1 
0     1    
1     2
```

#### Debug info

- Streamlit version: 1.16.0
- Python version: 3.8.15
- Using Conda: Yes
- OS version: Windows 11
- Browser version: Edge v108.0.1462.54

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that I would do it would be to store and retrieve the dataframe from a [session_state](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state) variable. This way you know that you are getting and working with the most up-to-date values.

- `st.session_state['df'] = df`  - will set the 'df' session state variable as the current `df`
- `st.session_state['df'] = df1` - will update the session state variable with the merged df

Here is an example:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

@st.experimental_memo
def read_df():
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'col1':[1,2],
        'col2':['A','B']
    })
    st.session_state['df'] = df
    return df

df = read_df()

def do_something():
    df1 = st.session_state['df']
    df_new = pd.DataFrame({
        'col1':[1,2],
        'col3':["X","Y"]
    })
    df1.drop(['col2'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
    df1 = df1.merge(df_new, on="col1")
    st.session_state['df'] = df1

st.button("Do Something", on_click=do_something, args =())
df = st.session_state['df']
download_csv = df.to_csv().encode('utf-8')
st.download_button('Download', data = download_csv, file_name = 'download_csv.csv', mime='text/csv')
```

#### Output file:

`file_name = 'download_csv.csv'`

```
   col1 col3
0     1    X
1     2    Y
```

#### Note:

`@st.experimental_memo` - ensures that the **df** is only **loaded once**.

Comment: Thanks for this! It is working now after I used your example. Do you consider this a bug or is this intentional? It's confusing that drop works but merge does not.

Comment: I am not 100% sure if it is a bug or not. It may be. But Streamlit has some weird requirements due to the session_state and how it handles variables on various actions. Anyway - I am glad you got it to work. Best of luck with your project.